# How can I get N distinct spectrum-like colors in Qt with starting color RED and ending color BLUE

Tags: c++, qt, colors, gradient, spectrum

Initially, I thought it can be easily implemented using a single for-loop with pre-calculated step size.

```
// blue = (240, 255, 255)
// red  = (0,   255, 255)
const int step = (240 - 0) / (N - 1);
QColor color;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  color.setHsv(i * step, 255, 255);
}
```

But as N grows larger, the ending color may not be what I expected.
For example (N == 82), ending color is hsv(162, 255, 255) instead of hsv(240, 255, 255).

My intention is to 1) generate N distinct color, 2) spectrum-like, 3) starts in RED and ends in BLUE.
Should I take S, V into consideration for my requirement as well?

Comment: Not sure what your actual goal is, but it's possible that [QGradient](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgradient.html) could help.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're choosing an integer step, and adding it to get from the smallest to the largest value. This has the advantage of spacing the hues evenly. But as you've observed, it has the disadvantage of getting the range wrong (possibly quite badly wrong) at times.

If you're willing to sacrifice a little in the way of the spacing of hues being perfectly even to get closer to filling the specified range, you can compute the step as a floating point number, do floating point multiplication, and round (or truncate) afterwards.

```cpp
std::vector<int> interpolate_range(int lower, int upper, int step_count) { 
    double step = (upper - lower) / (step_count - 1.0);

    std::vector<int> ret;
    for (int i=0; i<step_count; i++) {
        // step is a double, so `double * i` is done in floating
        // point, then the result is truncated to be pushed into
        // ret.
        ret.push_back(step * i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Skipping the other color components, and just printing out these values, we get this:

```
0   2   5   8   11  14  17  20  23  26  

29  32  35  38  41  44  47  50  53  56  

59  62  65  68  71  74  77  80  82  85  

88  91  94  97  100 103 106 109 112 115 

118 121 124 127 130 133 136 139 142 145 

148 151 154 157 160 162 165 168 171 174 

177 180 183 186 189 192 195 198 201 204 

207 210 213 216 219 222 225 228 231 234 

237 240
```

As you can see, we usually get a separation of 3, but a few times (0 to 2, 80 to 82 and 160 to 162) only 2, allowing us to fill the entire range.